# is there a way to retrieve information from a webpage and use that info to prefill another page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to create a browser extension or a javascript to retrieve pieces of information from a currently open webpage and use that info to prefill a form on another webpage.
So, for example, if I'm on a StackOverflow page, I'd like a script that takes info from that page (title, question,...) and prefill that data in a new webpage (eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).
I'm not an expert in coding, but I created some scripts using Python and Selenium (nothing too fancy though). I looked for a similar question, but I didn't find anything. Does anyone have an idea on how I could accomplish something like that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the help of content script. fetch the required data from any webpage using a content script and store the data on extension storage. Then you can inject the data to required input on required webpage with `executeScript()`

for more reference: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts